# Too many instances of DefaultEntry in Scala mutable.Map

Tags: scala, performance, apache-spark, visualvm

Scala 2.11 `mutable.Map` is instantiating too many `DefaultEntry`.

Code to reproduce:

```
val map: mutable.Map[Int, String] = mutable.Map()
(1 to 1000000).foreach(n => map(n.toString) = s"number $n")
```

Here's the memory sample from visualvm:
[image]

I wasn't expecting to see so many instances of `DefaultEntry`. What's the reason?

Comment: it really depends a lot on what your application is doing, and the code. maybe you have an hashmap somewhere. maybe you are itereating though the HashEntries...

Comment: If you look at the code to reproduce, it does nothing apart from creating the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct and instances also. Here you have 1_000_001 `n` and for each `n` you call:

```
map(n.toString) = s"number $n"
```

`map(key) = value` is just syntactic sugar for calling `update(key, value)` function.

Let's look at `update` implementation of `mutable.Map`, by default it will be `HashMap`:

```
override def update(key: A, value: B): Unit = put(key, value)
```

go to the `put`:

```
override def put(key: A, value: B): Option[B] = {
  val e = findOrAddEntry(key, value)
  if (e eq null) None
  else { val v = e.value; e.value = value; Some(v) }
}

protected def findOrAddEntry[B](key: A, value: B): Entry = {
  val h = index(elemHashCode(key))
  val e = findEntry0(key, h)
  if (e ne null) e else { addEntry0(createNewEntry(key, value), h); null }
}

protected def createNewEntry[B1](key: A, value: B1): Entry = {
  new Entry(key, value.asInstanceOf[B])
}
```

in the method `createNewEntry` `new Entry` is created. You call `update` on your `map` 1_000_001 times and `key` is always unique this is the reason you have 1_000_001 `DefaultEntry` objects.